How to deploy a backend express application that normally runs locally on AWS
So I have a repository of both frontend and backend for a portfolio. It looks like this:
portfolio_fullstack

backend

mike_prompt.txt
env.
node_modules
server.js
package
package-lock


frontend

react-stuff`



amplify.yml
I am focusing on the backend here. I was able to make AWS Amplify run using just the frontend folder, but I can't seem to make the backend folder run with it. I get stuck on how I should run this backend folder as it isn't as simple as using 'node server.js' when I run it locally. What should I do?
I tried to put it on AWS Lambda but the backend folder is over 10 MB and I am completely lost on it. I am just very, very confused on how I could run it as if I was just running it locally.


First, you can containerize your backend.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-node

Second, you can push the Docker image of your backend into Amazon ECR service within a repository.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html

Third, create a Lambda function using a container image hosting

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html
You can find a quick summary from AWS re:POST: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-container-images

If you are deploying to AWS Lambda, then the first link you provided is insufficient, since you have to build your containers in a very specific way for them to be compatible with AWS Lambda.

Thanks @MarkB, my 1st thinking is to give Michael the high-level of steps and what he can think for next steps. Yes, talking to containerize or modernize is a long way to go story, my provided URL may not cover exactly what he needs but as i mentioned.
